# Distributing python application

Tags: python

I am writing a quite large Python application; the application is actually to a large part a wrapping of several shared libraries written in C and C++(Qt). I am 'installing' this without administrator rights, so everything including shared libraries, binary and also Python modules must be in non-standard locations, i.e. I have a situation like this:

1. Shared libraries in /funny/path/lib
2. Python modules installed in /funny/path/python/lin
3. The python interpreter itself might also be in /nonstandard/location

The whole thing is distributed as open source, and I need to find a reasonably elegant and simple way to set the necessary environment variables. The whole thing is distributed with version control software; so the environment variables must be set in some 'local addition' i.e. something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /funny/path/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH /funn/path/python/lib:$PYTHONPATH

# 
exec python main.py
```

But I am programming in Python for a reason - I detest these shell scripts. Any views on the most elegant way to do this would be nice.

Joakim

Comment: I like the way you phrased your last paragraph :)

Comment: Why can't things be installed with administrator rights, in proper locations, and avoid the hated shell script?

Comment: As mentioned this is distributed as open source; and for others that would surely be the best situation. Myself I work in big-inflexible-corporation - Joe Average from the research department is NOT allowed to even think about installing something in e.g. /usr/local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why waste time detesting shell scripts?

Since you won't install in a standard location, (and can't seem to get sys admins to install needed packages in standard locations) that's almost your only alternative.

You can set the `PYTHONPATH` from within Python.  It's in `sys.path`.  Setting an environment variable (like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is harder, because Linux limits the ways in which applications can change the environment.

You can use `os.exec` to run a process in a modified environment.  It's a little odd using Python to then do `os.exec..e()` to invoke Python, but it is an easy way  to set an additional environment variable.

Comment: OK - thank you, I will stick to a shell script. What is the preferred way to invoke the final python program: (1): exec python script.py  (2):  python script.py   (3): script.py (with #! in script).